# NestJS - what are the best practices to consider return types of custom queries from the DAL?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, dto, data-access-layer

I have a project with NestJS where I use the classic controller-service-dal architecture.

Until recently, I performed only simple queries from the DAL which returned the models themselves (or entities if you prefer). Now I work on a query that alters the result with `projection` and `lookup` - so actually my return type is not the exact model. Here's an example: consider having a `Person` model which is the following:

```
type PersonModel = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  birthDate: Date;
}
```

but my query in the DAL returns an object in the following type:

```
type Result = {
  name: string; // this is the combination of firstName and lastName of the model
  birthDate: Date;
}
```

After that in the service I perform some conversions to the appropriate DTO which is the following:

```
type PersonDTO = {
  name: string;
  age: number; // this is computed by conversion in the service level
}
```

My main questions are:

1. How should I call the type `Result`? (I don't think `Result` is an appropriate name, I try to find some more professional convention like `DTO`, `Model`, etc.
2. Is it a better practice to create types like `Result` even the returned type from the `DAL` is the model itself? (meaning - the `DAL` in the example would return a result of type `PersonModel` and there are conversions in the service to the `PersonDTO`)

Comment: no clear answer here, I prefer to always use DTOs containing only the required fields between the layers, so entities never "leave" the data access layer

Comment: Is there a "better" name convention to the type instead if DTO? Because DTO (if I'm correct) is for object that are passed in the requests between client and api

Comment: imho DTO is used for passing data between layers, even frontend is just a layer. Perhaps something like BUSINESS_CASE_HERE_Result or ..._Response could be an option